# ScholarOne Manuscripts File Designations

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

When uploading files in SCHOLARONE Manuscripts (IEEE journals), I can pick an appropriate file designation for each. What is the file designations 'Summary of changes' and 'Summary of differences'?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary of Differences**: If you are submitting an extended version of a previously published work, you may be required to submit a "Summary of Differences" between the new work and the original.

**Summary of Changes**: If you have made revisions and are re-submitting a manuscript that has already been reviewed by this journal, you may upload a file in which you respond to the reviewers' questions and comments as a "Summary of Changes."

Comment: If some parts of the manuscript were published earlier, then should I upload previous papers fully (choosing the file destination ‘Previous Published Version(s)’ ), or upload summary of differences only? Thanks.